# Mapping a circle to curved space

Tags: geometry, circles, curves

I'm not sure how to state my question in proper mathematical terms, so I'll try to explain it here using some picture.
[image: Circle in flat and curved space].
On the left you see a circle defined by its center point c and its radius r. Also we have a point p which is defined as being the point on the circle alpha radians from the positive x axis. So far this should be pretty standard.

What I want to do now, is to map the left circle onto some curved space as illustrated on the right. In this example the curvature is set to k=1. The circle's center in curved space is set where the tangent lines (dashed blue) meet. The (now curved) arc should stay 2r which results in a new r'. Also there should be some mapping from alpha to alpha', because in the lower part of the circles the angles get compressed while they get stretched in the upper part.

What would be the mapping functions (c->c'; r->r'; alpha->alpha') given the constraints for the new circle ?

Sorry for not being able to describe this problem more rigorously in mathematical terms, but there should be a sensible mapping like this (and it most likely has a name as well ;) ).

Comment: In curved space, what is the meaning of "tangent lines meeting"?

Comment: I cannot follow your middle large paragraph. There are too many things you have not clearly defined (what is this curved space with a curvature of 1??).

Comment: @Paul you could see the black line as a part of a circle. on the left with radius=inf, on the right with radius=1

Comment: @Kapil It was hard to describe for me, but I was hoping it would be clear from the right image. Basically the 2 points where the black curve intersects the circle in right angles you draw the tangents of the black curve and where they meet is where the circle center is located (on the right it is a degenerate case since the 2 tangents would coincide)

Comment: Not sure a circle with radius infinity on the left and radius 1 on the right is helping me to understand...

Comment: @Paul imagine the black curve and the red circle to be orthogonal/perpendicular circles

Comment: Is the diameter of the first circle mapped to this circular arc of length 2r? Now you want to find equations relating c, r, and $\alpha$ in the first circle to c', r' and $\alpha '$ in the second?

Comment: @Lenny I was not clear in my question. What do you mean by lines in curved space? Do you mean geodesics? Is the black line not a geodesic?

Comment: @Paul yes and yes, that's precisely what i want to do.

Comment: @Kapil probably geodesic is the right world here (I'm not 100% sure if the terminology is right)

Comment: The distortion of length on the red circle and the bending of the black diameter into a circular arc suggest you're trying to apply a _Moebius transformation_ to the plane. A search for _circles of Apollonius_ may also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your diagrams and description are consistent with applying a [*Möbius transformation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) to a circle so that two points on a diameter are fixed. The circle sweeps out a family of [*circles of Apollonius*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius).

[image: Circles moved by a family of Moebius transformations]

This transformation is most easily described using complex numbers: If $p$ is a real number, and if $z = x + iy$ is complex, then the mapping
$$
f(z) = \frac{z + ip}{ipz + 1}
= \frac{x + i(y + p)}{1 - py + ipx}
= \frac{[x + i(y + p)][1 - py - ipx]}{(1 - py)^{2} + (px)^{2}}
$$
sends the unit circle ($z = e^{i\alpha}$, or $x = \cos\alpha$, $y = \sin\alpha$) to a circle passing through $\pm1$. (To handle a circle of radius $r$, replace $z$ by $z/r$.) The parameter $p$ controls the "amount of distortion". When $p = \pm1$, the distorted circle acquires infinite radius, and becomes the $x$-axis.

The bottom and top points of the distorted circle are
$$
f(-i) = i\frac{p - 1}{p + 1},\qquad
f(i) = i\frac{1 + p}{1 - p}.
$$
The center of the distorted circle is the midpoint, $\frac{1}{2}[f(i) + f(-i)]$; the radius of the distorted circle is half the magnitude of the difference, $\frac{1}{2}|f(i) - f(-i)|$. Thus
$$
\text{Center} = c' = i\frac{2p}{1 - p^{2}},\qquad
\text{radius} = r' = \frac{1 + p^{2}}{|1 - p^{2}|}.
$$
The image of the $x$-axis under this transformation is a circle orthogonal to the distorted circle.

If you're looking to plot these circles parametrically or otherwise describe points on the distorted circle corresponding to points on the original, you don't need $\alpha'$; just set $(x, y) = (\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)$. If it matters, however, you can calculate $\alpha'$ (a little tediously) by expressing $1 - c'$ and $f(z) - c'$ as plane vectors and using the dot product to find the angle they subtend.

Comment: this looks precisely like what i'm looking for. thank you very much for the detailed description. :)